# Do some changes in lib.d.ts

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

We are trying to translate a whole Javascript project into Typescript. In this project we use a variable called `Storage`, which is a keyword/protected word in Typescript.

This variable is used a lot, and it's a bit tricky to change it, so I'd prefer to change the `Storage` in the definition file lib.d.ts. But I'm not able to tell Visual Studio to use this new version of lib.d.ts, it always throws an error at compilation, even if the Intelli-sense is working correctly.
Is there a configuration thing I can change somewhere ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `lib.d.ts` file simply describes what will be available at runtime, in this case the [DOM Storage interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage).

Removing the clash in `lib.d.ts` won't remove any clashes at runtime.

One possible temporary fix is supplied by the fact that interfaces are open in TypeScript, which would allow you add to it, for example, you could include the following instead of changing `lib.d.ts` in order to get compilation...

```
interface Storage {
     myCustomThing(a: string): number;
}
```

This will allow you to compile and get your code base into TypeScript, at which point you can use Visual Studio to refactor the name of your Storage variable to avoid the clash.

Here is a working version on the [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=interface%20Storage%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20myCustomThing%28a%3a%20string%29%3a%20number;%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20storage%20=%20new%20Storage%28%29;%0Astorage.myCustomThing%28%27input%27%29;).

Comment: It doesn't work for me, VS just keep the definition from lib.d.ts and ignore my add :(

Comment: I will add a link to the working version in the TypeScript Playground - you may need to share your non working version to get help making it work.

Comment: Ok I see, the problem in my code is we are using 'Storage' as a global variable name. We are not using it this way : `var storage = new Storage();` but like `Storage.stuff = ...`

Comment: Ok we solved it with `interface newStorage {stuff: any;}
var newStorage: newStorage = <any>Storage;` Dirty but it works ! (And still have to change all the `Storage` reference in all new typescript fles )

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that it's possible to change it in Visual Studio. You may want to take a look at here:
http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/429115